# CSS border-collapse not working in <table>

Tags: html, css

I'm having an impossible time getting `border-collapse` to work for me. The page I'm working with has a table in it. The table has 2 columns, one for a label and the other for data. Sometimes there is no data to display, but I still need to rendor the table row and label column because I have a JQuery script that might need to write data to the data column. In other words, regardless of whether there is data or not, I need to rendor the table row as a placeholder. If there is no data I want the row to collapse.

In the html below, `visibility:hidden` is working since I won't see the label 'Condition:', but the row doesn't collapse. I've tried looking at it in FireFox 13, Safari 5 and IE 8. All three show the same problem - the row never ccollapses even though it doesn't display anything.

```
#data
{
    font-size: 95%;
}
#data table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#data table td
{
    padding-left: 5px;
}


<div id="data">

....

    <table>
        <tr style="visibility:hidden;">
            <td><div class="datalabel">Condition:</div></td>
            <td class="datainfo"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

....

</div>
```

What more do I need to do to make this happen? I'd like it to be cross-browser compatible. I'm trying to support IE7 and above. I'm guessing someone is going to give me hell for using a table in the first place... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The visibility property determines whether a given element is visible
>   or not (visibility="visible|hidden"). However, when visibility is set
>   to hidden, the element being hidden still occupies its same place in
>   the layout of the page.

[Display VS Visibility](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13638)

use `display:none;` to hide and `display:block;` to show

```
   <table style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr style="display:none;">
            <td><div class="datalabel">Condition:</div></td>
            <td class="datainfo"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**Note**: `border-collapse:collapse;` is used in a situation, where you have borders specified for container and the contained and you want border to be displayed once.

Comment: Hey! `display:none` worked! I haven't tried using `display:block` from the JQuery to get it to open up, yet. Thank you CoDe aDDict!

Comment: Btw, you're saying I don't need to use `border-collapse` to get this to work? The rows that will need `display:none` aren't in any order. Could be first row, third, fourth or none at all.

Comment: I don't know about the rest of your html. if you have this only table. then you don't need it. try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="0" cellpading="0" cellspacing="0">
```

and try to use and `&nbps;` or something like that, if you don't have data in a cell

something like:

```
<table border="0" cellpading="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr style="visibility:hidden;">
        <td><div class="datalabel">Condition:</div></td>
        <td class="datainfo">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Alex, I did as you said, but the hidden row still takes up vertical whitespace. Also, I edited my question to include the actual CSS I'm using. I took the style attributes out of the html markup.